# How do I obtain the return address from the stack pointer in C?

Tags: c

Sorry my C is a bit rusty.

I would like to get the return address as an exercise using only the address of the stack pointer. **I know I can directly get the return address using the `__builtin_return_address` function but I want to do it manually with the stack pointer.**

Right now I just have the address of the pointer to the return address, but I would like to get the actual address.

```
void a() {
    void *sp = __builtin_frame_address(0);
    printf("%p\n", (*(&sp) + 0x8));
}

int main() {
    a();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693011/how-can-i-determine-the-return-address-on-stack

Comment: `void *addr = __builtin_extract_return_addr (__builtin_return_address (0));`? In your `printf` maybe you want this `printf("%p\n", ((char *)sp) + 8);`

Comment: There is no way to do this in standard C and how to do it depends on what target system you've got. Typically you do it with inline assembler.

Comment: @basepusher: getting the return address from the frame pointer is not straightforward. It depends on many factors known to the compiler only. It may vary from one function to another.

Comment: Do you want a general solution? (Hint: It is **not** possible in C.) Or do you want something that works just with the specific compiler in the specific version on your specific system and with the specific function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [GNU documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) for this extension:

> **6.51 Getting the Return or Frame Address of a Function**
>
> These functions may be used to get information about the callers of a function.
>
> Built-in Function: `void * __builtin_return_address (unsigned int level)`
>
> This function returns the return address of the current function, or of one of its callers. The level argument is number of frames to scan up the call stack. A value of `0` yields the return address of the current function, a value of `1` yields the return address of the caller of the current function, and so forth. When inlining the expected behavior is that the function returns the address of the function that is returned to. To work around this behavior use the *noinline* function attribute.
>
> The level argument must be a constant integer.
>
> On some machines it may be impossible to determine the return address of any function other than the current one; in such cases, or when the top of the stack has been reached, this function returns an unspecified value. In addition, `__builtin_frame_address` may be used to determine if the top of the stack has been reached.
>
> Additional post-processing of the returned value may be needed, see `__builtin_extract_return_addr`.
>
> The stored representation of the return address in memory may be different from the address returned by `__builtin_return_address`. For example, on AArch64 the stored address may be mangled with return address signing whereas the address returned by `__builtin_return_address` is not.
>
> Calling this function with a nonzero argument can have unpredictable effects, including crashing the calling program. As a result, calls that are considered unsafe are diagnosed when the `-Wframe-address` option is in effect. Such calls should only be made in debugging situations.
>
> On targets where code addresses are representable as `void *`,
>
> `void *addr = __builtin_extract_return_addr(__builtin_return_address(0));`
> gives the code address where the current function would return. For example, such an address may be used with dladdr or other interfaces that work with code addresses.
>
> Built-in Function: `void * __builtin_extract_return_addr(void *addr)`
>
> The address as returned by `__builtin_return_address` may have to be fed through this function to get the actual encoded address. For example, on the 31-bit S/390 platform the highest bit has to be masked out, or on SPARC platforms an offset has to be added for the true next instruction to be executed.
>
> If no fixup is needed, this function simply passes through `addr`.
>
> Built-in Function: `void * __builtin_frob_return_addr(void *addr)`
>
> This function does the reverse of `__builtin_extract_return_addr`.
>
> Built-in Function: `void * __builtin_frame_address(unsigned int level)`
>
> This function is similar to `__builtin_return_address`, but it returns the address of the function frame rather than the return address of the function. Calling `__builtin_frame_address` with a value of `0` yields the frame address of the current function, a value of `1` yields the frame address of the caller of the current function, and so forth.
>
> The frame is the area on the stack that holds local variables and saved registers. The frame address is normally the address of the first word pushed on to the stack by the function. However, the exact definition depends upon the processor and the calling convention. If the processor has a dedicated frame pointer register, and the function has a frame, then `__builtin_frame_address` returns the value of the frame pointer register.
>
> On some machines it may be impossible to determine the frame address of any function other than the current one; in such cases, or when the top of the stack has been reached, this function returns 0 if the first frame pointer is properly initialized by the startup code.
>
> Calling this function with a nonzero argument can have unpredictable effects, including crashing the calling program. As a result, calls that are considered unsafe are diagnosed when the `-Wframe-address` option is in effect. Such calls should only be made in debugging situations.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void a() {
    printf("return address: %p\n", __builtin_extract_return_addr(__builtin_return_address(0)));
}

int main() {
    a();
    return 0;
}
```

Getting the return address from the frame address is not always possible and is very system specific, it also depends on the function calling convention. The compiler takes these factors into consideration when compiling the builtin `__builtin_return_address`, it is quite tricky to try and do it by hand from the value of `__builtin_frame_address`.

If your goal is to construct an introspection system, you may have to store the frame and the return addresses separately. You will need to parse debugging information to try and make sense of the data accessible through these pointers.